# Procedure or function "Procedure name" expects a parameter "Param name" which was not supplied occurs rarely

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a web service function in VB.NET that will send parameters to a SQL Server stored procedure.

Everything works perfectly for two months in the deployed machine.

But now the error

> Procedure or function GetEmployeeDetails expects a parameter @Progress which was not supplied'

occurred only once on the deployed machine.

Before and after the error everything works fine.

Web service code:

```
 Public Function GetLocation(ByVal oldNumber As Integer, ByVal NewNumber As Integer, ByVal Location As String,ByVal Progress As String, ByVal Name As String, ByVal ID As String) As String
 Try
    Command1 = New SqlCommand("GetEmployeeDetails", connection1)

    With Command1
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .Parameters.Add("@oldNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = oldNumber
        .Parameters.Add("@NewNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NewNumber
        .Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = Location
        .Parameters.Add("@Progress", SqlDbType.Char, 10).Value = IIf(Progress = "", System.DBNull.Value, Progress)
        .Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Name
        .Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ID

        .Connection.Open()
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
        .Connection.Close()
    End With
```

Stored procedure params:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetEmployeeDetails 
(
    @oldNumber AS INTEGER,
    @NewNumber AS INTEGER, 
    @Location AS VARCHAR(10),
    @Progress AS CHAR(1),
    @Name AS VARCHAR(50),
    @ID AS VARCHAR(50)
) 
As
```

I just want to know why the error occured when all the parameters are passed correctly?

Comment: Can you try to pass in something else other than `DBNull.Value` to `@Progress`? If the value is empty (`""`) - can you just pass in a `*` or something? This error ("parameter was not supplied") can happen if you don't supply a value for a given parameter, e.g. if your source value happens to be null or empty

Comment: marc_s Is it wrong if I pass DBNULL.Value but it works correctly all the time.

Comment: Not sure if it's really the `@Progress` parameter - but I suspect one of the parameters is getting set to null or empty and thus the stored procedure then "thinks" it didn't get a value ....

Comment: Is @Progress CHAR(1) or CHAR(10)?

Comment: It is Char(1) but used as char(10) in VB.NET is that make any Diff

Comment: Even  @Progress param value is 'nothing or empty'. only DBNULL.value is sent by IIF() function, There is no such possibility of empty or nothing.

Comment: Could be an error in your VB code while assigning the parameter values, so it ends up in the catch handler. Also, it's a good practice to have default values for procedure parameters.

Comment: Is there any possibility to figure out the exact reason of the error.

Comment: Post mortem? Not very likely. If you had a trace set up it would be benefitial to see what was sent to the server. Without that we can only guess.

Comment: K, I will maintain logging to check for the error. Is that IIF() function return nothing at any case.

Comment: IS that the problem is because of DLL cache? Because my odd DLL dont have @Progress parameter..

Comment: I guess your variable "Progress" is sometimes null ... if you pass null (not DBNull) to a sproc you'll get the exception you describe

Answer (score 0):

Since you are Declaring Parameter as CHAR(1) in sql but used like Char(10) in Vb.net.

Try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetEmployeeDetails 
(
    @oldNumber AS INTEGER,
    @NewNumber AS INTEGER, 
    @Location AS VARCHAR(10),
    @Progress AS CHAR(10),
    @Name AS VARCHAR(50),
    @ID AS VARCHAR(50)
) 
As
```

Comment: The Error Occures rarely. Is really the Char declaration make a big difference. Because when we pass 10 character to Sql variable that is declared as Char(1) it will truncate the characters except first one.